Reference for finite global dimension of an acyclic bound quiver
I am looking for a proof of the following fact:

Let $(Q,I)$ be a bound quiver with $Q$ acyclic and $I$ admissible. Then for any representation $M$ there exists a projective resolution of length at most $n$, where $n$ is the number of vertices of $Q$.

The result can be found in Proposition 3.1.7 of An Introduction to Quiver Representations by Derksen and Weyman. However, the proof is not clear to me. There should be other references for this, but I can only find the case where $I = Q$, which implies that the path algebra is hereditary (see e.g. Intuition behind the canonical projective resolution of a quiver representation).

I think you meant "the case where $I=0$".

Since $Q$ is acyclic, there is a total ordering $<$ on the vertices of $Q$ such that if $i<j$, then there are no arrows from $i$ to $j$.  (To construct such an ordering, choose a sink $i$ of $Q$, declare it to be the smallest vertex; then remove $i$, and apply induction on the resulting quiver.)  This order is such that the indecomposable projective module $P_i$ at vertex $i$ is supported on vertices $j\leq i$.  From now on, we label the vertices of $Q$ with $1,2,\ldots, n$ in such a way that the order $<$ coincides with the order of the labelling.
We prove the following: if $m$ is the largest vertex on which $M$ is supported, then $M$ has a projective resolution of length at most $m$.  The proof is by induction: if $m=1$, then $M$ is supported on a sink and is thus projective.  Otherwise, let $P\xrightarrow{f} M$ be the projective cover of $M$.  Thanks to the ordering $<$, we get that $P$ is supported on vertices at most $m$; moreover, at vertex $m$, the support of $P$ and $M$ are identified by $f$ (this is because the tops of $M$ and $P$ are identified, and the supports of $M$ and $P$ at $m$ are part of their tops).  Thus the kernel of $f$ is supported in vertices strictly less than $m$.  The result is thus proved by induction.
